# cvtcolor crash with gpumat

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to do something very simple, convert an image to gray with the cuda cvtcolor function.

I have a gpuMat that I want to turn gray to use in some functions, what I'm doing:

```
GpuMat grey;
std::cout << "channels: " << img.channels() << std::endl;
std::cout << "depth: " << img.depth() << std::endl;
cv::cuda::cvtColor(img, grey, cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
std::cout << "converted" << std::endl;
```

What I get:

```
channels: 4
depth: 0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

For more information I have compiled:

- opencv: 4.4.0
- cuda: 10.2

Thanks in advance

After catching the error and printing it, I see the following error:

> OpenCV(4.4.0)
> /tmp/build_opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/cudev/include/opencv2/cudev/grid/detail/transform.hpp:264:
> error: (-217:Gpu API call) no kernel image is available for execution
> on the device in function 'call'

I put a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat frame;
    cout << "hola" << endl;
    VideoCapture cap;

    cap.open(0, cv::CAP_ANY);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }


    cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_mat;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);

        gpu_mat.upload(frame);
        cuda::cvtColor(gpu_mat, gpu_mat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        gpu_mat.download(frame);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("Live", frame);
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you try to post a [mcve]?

Comment: I edited the question with an example, thanks